# Dropdown click not working in Selenium RC

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

I am trying to automate  test scripts in selenium. **Scenario of the activity to be automated:**

1. It should open automatically a page URL first.
2. Click on the left navigation.
3. The page then gets populated with a drop-down, it should select a fixed value from the drop down(say = company)
4. Click a create button at the bottom of the page.

In my case the code is working until the population of drop down but after that the code fails to click the create button as the next action. The error message which I got in the command console is as follows:

> Element name = create not found on session c48334c30....96ed

Here is my code:

```
public class testing {

    Selenium selenium = null;

    @Test
    public void submit() throws Exception {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4545, "*firefox", "URL");
        selenium.start();
        selenium.open("URL");
        selenium.windowFocus();
        selenium.windowMaximize();
        selenium.click("link=Work with company names");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.select("//select[@name='company_id']", "label=company");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("3000");
        selenium.click("name = create");

    }
}
```

Please provide me your suggestions to solve this, since I am not able to understand why it  is failing to click the button named "create". I also tried to use `selenium.click("xpath=//button[matches(@id,'.*create')]");` instead of `selenium.click("name = create")` but it didnt work as well.

Please let me know what can be the issue for this error and how can I resolve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) it would be good if you provide html code of your page.

2) before clicking any element (which is loaded after some action) I recommend using WaitForElementPresent (from Selenium IDE), i.e. be sure that element really exists. Selenium works rather fast and it may try clicking the element before the element actually loaded.

You may use something like this:

```
public bool waitForElementPresent(string Xpath) {
bool present = false;
for (int second = 0; ; second++) {
if (second >= 5) {
break;
}
if (IsElementPresent(Xpath)) {
present = true;
break;
}
Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
return present;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
selenium.click("//*[contains(@name,'create')]");
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using: selenium.waitForPageToLoad("3000");
Selenium is waiting for page to load. You want to add a pause, though thread.sleep isn't the best practise it can still work for you.